# usr/bin/python showing an older version of python?

Tags: python, python-venv

I have been having trouble with my virtual environments. I have packages I want installed, but I believe I am running an old version of python. When I run `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` in my terminal, I get like 6 lines in return, most of which say python 2.7, like so:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66880 Mar 21  2019 /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel    925 Feb 22  2019 /usr/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Mar 28  2019 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Mar 28  2019 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66880 Mar 21  2019 /usr/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Mar 28  2019 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

However, when I run `pip -V` I get Python 3.7, like so:

```
pip 19.2.3 from /Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

which is what I want. It seems as though I’m running python 2.7? I’m a noob when it comes to environments. When I check my environments on Anaconda Navigator, they all say python is 3.7. I’m not sure what’s going on here. Any help is greatly greatly appreciated. I’m on Mac.

Comment: When you activate your python environment in conda, what is the output of "ls -la \`which python\`"

Comment: I realized I have multiple versions of python on my computer. python versions found: 
 /usr/local/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python. The current running version is usr/bin/python, which is running 2.7. I would like usr/local/bin/python3 to be the running version. @jhso

Comment: I'm assuming this is outside of your conda environment. You just need to make it so that your path searches /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin which is in your `$PATH` environment. This can be done manually (search changing your PATH variable) or in your .bashrc file. Changes to .bashrc will persist across boots, whereas setting your PATH manually will need to be done each boot.

Answer (score 0):

I appears that `python3` may work to launch a more recent Python. If that does not work, then you may want to add something like this to your ~/.bashrc file:

```sh
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/:$PATH"
```

Then restart your terminal.

You may also want to [become familiar with virtual environments](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/python-tools-for-managing-virtual-environments-3bko). This should work for you:

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
python -m site
```

Or, if you have Conda:

```
conda create --name env385 python=3.8.5
conda activate env385
python -m site
```